# Error: The constructor Object(EditText) is undefined

Tags: android

I'm getting an error in this method: "The constructor Object(EditText) is undefined"

```
private void setupAlert()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupAlert()");
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.emaildialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        final EditText userInput = (EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTxtEmailAddress);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                updatePref(userInput.getText().toString());
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "setupAlert: getPreference()=" + getPreference());
                takeSnapNow();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.colour_selector);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: getPreference()=" + getPreference());
        if (getPreference().equals("")) {
            setupAlert();
            takeSnapNow();
        } else {
            takeSnapNow();
        }
    }

private void takeSnapNow()
    {
        String fileName = "TempImage.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Captured by XYZ app");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Please suggest the solution to this error.

Edit: Corrected the above error by removing UserInput as suggested by others. However the alertDialog is still not shown. The logic is to check the sharedpref initially in onCreate, and if not found, call setupAlert() method to get email ID from user.
Any clues? Changed code updated in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DialogInterface.OnClickListener` doesn't take an `EditText` as  a constructor parameter and you don't need to do that ! you can use `userInput` without passing it to `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, just use it as follow

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: The alertDialog is not being shown when the above method is hit. Any clues?

Comment: Everything is fine now and there is no error in your method, where you have called this method ?

Comment: This is called from onCreate(). Code snippet updated to show the complete flow.

Comment: Are you sure `getPreference().equals("")` return true ? if not, then the method will not invoked

Comment: Yes, It returns TRUE. I verified the log. "setupAlert()" is being printed in the log.

Comment: The code have been tested and it's worked without any problem, can you make sure you don't have anything that hide the dialog inside the `takeSnapNow` method

Comment: takeSnapNow() uses the Android camera to capture the snap. I've added that method also in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "*new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(userInput)*"?

Just use new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()